# Procedure for LUN assigning and scanning on LInux server with two HBA card each with two port

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, storage, centos-6

Need a brief overview of LUN assigning and scanning on Linux server with fibre channel  switch.
On the server there is 2 HBA card installed each with two ports. Below are the few queries:

1. What are the details we need to provide the Storage team for assigning the LUN?
2. Whether the WWN number of both the HBA needs to be given to Storage Team?
3. What command will be used to scan the LUN on Linux server?
4. What does the command **echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/host/issue_lip** does in the background when we run it. And what is the impact of running this command on a running production server. Or we need to run this once we have down time.
5. What configuration needs to be done in multipath.

Please help me in understanding the process.

Answer (score -2):

I'm quite new at this but I will try to answer.

- What are the details we need to provide the Storage team for assigning the LUN?

  Well, basically you need to tell Storage team the amount of LUNs you need and the capacity of each LUN along with the WWN of the HBAs (see next answer below).
- Whether the WWN number of both the HBA needs to be given to Storage Team?

  Here you have to give the Storage team the WWN of the port which fibre is physically connected to. E.g., I have a HP blade with two ports en RHEL6 installed.

  ```
  [root@myserver ~]# more /sys/class/fc_host/host?/port_state
  ::::::::::::::
  /sys/class/fc_host/host0/port_state
  ::::::::::::::
  Online
  ::::::::::::::
  /sys/class/fc_host/host1/port_state
  ::::::::::::::
  Online
  [root@myserver ~]#
  ```

  Note both ports are "Online", which means they are connected to the SAN Switches.

  ```
  [root@myserver ~]# more /sys/class/fc_host/host?/port_name
  ::::::::::::::
  /sys/class/fc_host/host0/port_name
  ::::::::::::::
  0x10000000c9690826
  ::::::::::::::
  /sys/class/fc_host/host1/port_name
  ::::::::::::::
  0x10000000c9690827
  [root@myserver ~]#
  ```

  Here you can find the WWN of each port connected to the switch, here 0x10000000c9690826 and 0x10000000c9690827 are the WWN you have to give the Storage team.
- What command will be used to scan the LUN on Linux server?

  Well, in RHEL 6/7 is simple.

  1. First find out how many bus adapters you have:

     ```
     [root@myserver ~]# ls /sys/class/fc_host/
     host0  host1
     ```

     Note: I have two as you can see above
  2. Then scan for new LUNs.

     ```
     [root@myserver ~]# echo "1"     > /sys/class/fc_host/host0/issue_lip
     [root@myserver ~]# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan
     [root@myserver ~]# echo "1"     > /sys/class/fc_host/host1/issue_lip
     [root@myserver ~]# echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan
     ```

     Please see the link below for details:
     https://www.unixarena.com/2013/06/how-to-scan-new-fc-luns-and-scsi-disks.html/
- What does the command `echo "1" > /sys/class/fc_host/host/issue_lip` does in the background when we run it? And what is the impact of running this command on a running production server? Or we need to run this once we have down time?

  As I said in the beginning, I'm quite new at this and I don't know what it does in the background, but in my experience you can run the discovery procedure in a production server without affecting the service.
- What configuration needs to be done in multipath?

  Well, again, in RHEL6/7 you need the package device-mapper-multipath in order to work with multipath, and multipathd service should be running. When you run "multipath" command, it will discover multipathed devices. You can find more details in the link below:

  https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-install-and-configure-device-mapper-multipath-in-centos-rhel-67/

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please leave a comment to explain your downvote, otherwise this new user is unlikely to figure how on his own in what way his question doesn't meet site standards.